# What is defs in javascript/svg

Tags: javascript, svg

```
svg.append("defs")
.append("filter").attr("id", "blur")
.attr("x", "-50%").attr("y", "-50%")
.attr("height", "200%").attr("width", "200%")
.append("feGaussianBlur").attr("in", "SourceGraphic").attr("stdDeviation", 10);
```

I saw these code in javascript. I try to google, but still can not understand what is a "defs" in js.

BTW, can anyone explain what is a "filter"?

Many thanks!

Comment: They are strings. What meaning they have depends on what kind of object `svg` is and what the `append` method does with it.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything in Javascript, it means something to the SVG. You should reformulate and retag your question if you want answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like your code is some implementation of a Gaussian blur filter using SVG. So `defs` and `filter` there are really SVG concepts, not so much JavaScript.

### `defs`

> SVG allows graphical objects to be defined for later reuse. It is
>   recommended that, wherever possible, referenced elements be defined
>   inside of a defs element. Defining these elements inside of a defs
>   element promotes understandability of the SVG content and thus
>   promotes accessibility. Graphical elements defined in a defs will not
>   be directly rendered. You can use a  element to render those
>   elements wherever you want on the viewport.

### `filter`

> The filter element serves as container for atomic filter operations.
>   It is never rendered directly. A filter is referenced by using the
>   filter attribute on the target SVG element.

### `feGaussianBlur`

> The filter blurs the input image by the amount specified in
>   stdDeviation, which defines the bell-curve.

**Documentation from Mozilla**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/filter

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feGaussianBlur